# BBCode with XSS escape?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, bbcode

There is a string like:

```
jaksldhfklajsfdhdkjf[bbcode]img url[/bbcode]kjalhdfk<script>alert(1)</script>sdlfjah
```

…and I want it to become:

```
jaksldhfklajsfdhdkjf<img src="img url" />kjalhdfk&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;sdlfjah
```

…using JavaScript only.

I can't find a JS library that can do it.
Is there a completed library or another way (or different logic) to prevent unsafe input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you are trying to do is by making escapement replacements *before* parsing the BBCode.

```
function escape(s) { // http://escape.alf.nu/
    function html(a) {
        return {'>':'&gt;', '<':'&lt;', '"':'&quot;'}[a] || a;
    }
    s = s.replace(/[<>"]/g, html);
    s = s.replace(/\[bbcode]((?:http:|ftp:\/)\/\/.*?)\[\/bbcode]/g, '<img src="$1">');
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious why didn't I figure out this myself D:
This is obiously simple D: just need to escape _before_ parsing
Although I found this one week after I ask the question, I didn't find that I need to whitelist _javascript:_ .
After all, thanks for answering